# C# Adding "Current" property to a list class inheriting from list<T>

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, ienumerator

I want to add the "Current" property to my list class VolumeList.
Here's my code:

```
class Volume
{
    private string name;
    private string color;
    private bool has_segment;

    public Volume(string Name, string color, bool has_segment)

    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.has_segment = has_segment;

  public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set { color = value; }
    }
    public bool HasSegment
    {
        get { return has_segment; }
        set { has_segment = value; }
    }
    public static ROOTList<Volume> VolumeList{ get; set; } = new ROOTList<Volume>();
}


public class ROOTList<T> : List<T>
{


    public T Last
    {
        get
        {
            return this[this.Count - 1];
        }
        set
        {
            this[this.Count - 1] = value;
        }
    }
    public T First
    {
        get
        {
            return this[0];
        }
        set
        {
            this[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public T Current
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to add the "Current" property/method in order to use it like this:

```
Volume.VolumeList.Current.Name (I get the name of the current volume)
Volume.VolumeList.Current.Name = "test" (I set the name "test" to the current volume).
```

`First` and "Last` methods are working.

Please, do you have any solutions?

Best regards

Comment: What is your concept of "current"? First and Last are absolute positions... But current? How do you define it?

Comment: Usually, one would prefer to just use `List<T>` and the existing LINQ methods `First()` and `Last()` - no need to derive an own ist class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. "Current"  allow me to step through the list. It also keeps track of which item I'm working with. It relates to the index of the collection/list. LINQ doesn't have this concept?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a few options on how to do this. As you're just starting out, I'd say use option 1 as this is a lot simpler.

## Option 1: Basic using LINQ

Below is a `Volume` class and a `Main` method which shows examples of usage. You can use Linq to get the first/last items in the list of volumes and then you can set properties on individual items in the list by using `volumes[i]` where `i` is the index of the item in the list.

You can also use Linq to find particular volumes based on `Color`, `Name`, `HasVolume` and then change properties on each of those using a `foreach` loop.

More info on LINQ is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/.

Take a look at the example below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var volumes = new List<Volume>();
            var volume1 = new Volume("vol1", "red", true);
            var volume2 = new Volume("vol2", "red", true);

            volumes.Add(volume1); //adds the first volume
            volumes.Add(volume2); //adds the second volume
            var lastVolume = volumes.First(); //gets the first volume
            var firstVolume = volumes.Last(); //gets the last volume
            volumes[0].Color = "blue"; //sets the first volume color to blue
            volumes[1].Color = "green"; //sets the second volume color to green

            // set all green volumes to purple
            var greenVolumes = volumes.Where(v => v.Color == "green");
            foreach (var greenVolume in greenVolumes)
            {
                greenVolume.Color = "purple";
            }
        }
    }

    public class Volume
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public bool HasSegment { get; set; }

        public Volume(string name, string color, bool hasSegment)
        {
            Name = name;
            Color = color;
            HasSegment = hasSegment;
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 2: More advanced using the Iterator pattern

Take a look at the iterator pattern here: https://www.dofactory.com/net/iterator-design-pattern.

Basically, it will allow you to step through the list by selecting `MoveNext()`, `Last`, `First`, and `Current`. I've added a `_current` field which keeps track of which item you are working with. It relates to the index of the collection/list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Sandbox
{
    public class Volume
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public bool HasSegment { get; set; }

        public Volume(string name, string color, bool hasSegment)
        {
            Name = name;
            Color = color;
            HasSegment = hasSegment;
        }
    }

    public class Iterator<T>
    {
        private readonly List<T> _items;
        private int _index;

        public T Last
        {
            get => _items[_items.Count - 1];
            set => _items[_items.Count - 1] = value;
        }

        public T First
        {
            get => _items[0];
            set => _items[0] = value;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get => _items[_index];
            set => _items[_index] = value;
        }

        public Iterator(List<T> items)
        {
            _items = items;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_index == _items.Count - 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                _index++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like in this unit test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsNextThenSetsCurrentByProperty()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.MoveNext();
            sut.Current.Name = "vol2modifiedAgain";

            Assert.Equal("vol2modifiedAgain", sut.Current.Name);
        }
```

Unit tests are here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication1.Sandbox;
using Xunit;

namespace WebApplication1.Tests
{
    public class VolumeIteratorTests
    {
        private List<Volume> _volumes => new List<Volume>()
            {
                new Volume("vol1", "green", true),
                new Volume("vol2", "green", true)
            };

        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsCurrent()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);

            Assert.Equal("vol1", sut.Current.Name);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsNext()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.MoveNext();

            Assert.Equal("vol2", sut.Current.Name);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsNextThenSetsCurrent()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.MoveNext();
            sut.Current = new Volume("vol2modified", "green", false);

            Assert.Equal("vol2modified", sut.Current.Name);
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsNextThenSetsCurrentByProperty()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.MoveNext();
            sut.Current.Name = "vol2modifiedAgain";

            Assert.Equal("vol2modifiedAgain", sut.Current.Name);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsLast()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            
            Assert.Equal("vol2", sut.Last.Name);
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorSetsLast()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.Last = new Volume("last", "red", true);

            Assert.Equal("last", sut.Last.Name);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorGetsFirst()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);

            Assert.Equal("vol1", sut.First.Name);
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public void VolumeIteratorSetsFirst()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.First = new Volume("first", "red", true);

            Assert.Equal("first", sut.First.Name);
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public void MoveNextReturnsTrueIfNotLastItem()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            
            Assert.True(sut.MoveNext());
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public void MoveNextReturnsFalseIfLastItem()
        {
            var sut = new Iterator<Volume>(_volumes);
            sut.MoveNext();

            Assert.False(sut.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Swordfish! That is exactly what I need :)

Comment: @Chamard33 - I also added a simpler version using LINQ for you. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a nice method to add a Volume to the new "sut" List? Can we add the "Add" method to the Iterator<T> class? Or I need to write '_volumes.Add(new Volume("vol3", "yellow", true));' to do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you can add an `Add` method which takes a `volume` as a parameter and uses `_volumes.Add(volume)` to add it to the list. Note that the `VolumeIteratorTests` class contains unit tests rather than actual application code but it's an example of how you can use the iterator.

Comment: That's really clear! Thanks a lot for everything

Comment: If you don't have a need for a dedicated iterator, it's going to be best to use Option 1 in my answer above which has an example for how to add an item to a list. Option 1 is a lot simpler. If you do need to use the iterator for some reason then you can add an `Add` method to it even though the `List<T> _items` is `readonly`. This method would simply look like this:

`public void Add(T item) => _items.Add(item);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I set by myself the "Current" item? I mean for example VolumeList.Current = "vol1"? VolumeList.Current will be the object Volume with the property "Name" "vol1". Thans a lot:)